# Suggestions for a Complex Number Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I am trying to work on a seemingly forward proof but I am not sure if I am taking the right approach. It is $$\mathrm ZW=0 $$ where Z and W are any complex numbers implies that $\mathrm Z=0$ or $\mathrm W=0 $.

What I have tried,

Let Z=(a+bi) and  let W=(c+di)

Then ZW=(a+bi)(c+di)=(ac+adi+bdi-bd)=0

(ac-bd)+(ad+bd)i=0

Now I know for ZW to be zero, then both the real and imaginary part must be zero ie ac-bd=0 and ad+bc=0. Im not sure how to go about proving anything from just this though? Any hints , answers, help, suggestions?

Thanks all

Comment: You could try proving that $|ab|=|a|\cdot |b|$ and appeal to the fact that the product of two positive numbers is positive, thus either $|a|$ or $|b|$ is $0$. Another approach would be to represent your complexes as $re^{i\theta}$, if you're aware of that representation.

Comment: The product of two positive numbers is positive yea, does this hold for complex numbers?

Comment: It doesn't need to; $|a|$, $|b|$ and $|ab|$ are all real.

Comment: Alternatively, you can multiply by the conjugate(s) and find $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=0$. This is an equation in real numbers, just the working out of @Meelo’s suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways. You reached (with a small typo) the fact that $ac-bd=0$ and $ad+bc=0$. Let us go on from there.

Note the following important identity
$$(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2).$$
This identity, sometimes called the Brahmagupta-Fibonacci Identity, can be verified by multiplying out both sides. More nicely, it can be obtained  as per the comment of Lubin.

So from your equations we conclude that $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=0$. Thus either $a^2+b^2=0$, forcing $a=b=0$, or $c^2+d^2=0$, forcing $c=d=0$.

**Remark:** Possibly you have already met the notion of norm of a complex number $a+bi$. The Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity says that the norm of a product of two complex numbers is the product of the norms.

Comment: Thanks, so is it okay to have it with the squares when originally I only have (ac-bd)+(ad+cb)?

Comment: You originally have $(ac-bd)+i(ad+bc)=0$, which is equivalent to the system $ac-bd=0$, $ad+bc=0$, which is equivalent to the system $(ac-bd)^2=0$, $(ad+bc)^2=0$. The rest is as above.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $z\ne 0$ and $w\ne 0$, then there are numbers $z',w'$ such that $zz'=1$ and $ww'=1$
therefore $(zw)(z'w')=1$ and therefore $zw\ne 0$ since $a\cdot 0=0$ for any $a\in\Bbb C$.

Comment: Thanks, so do all complex numbers other than zero have a multiplicative inverse?

Comment: Yes, if $z\ne 0$, then $z\cdot{\overline z\over|z|}=\frac{|z|}{|z|}=1$.

Comment: The fact that the complex numbers have no zero divisors (the current question) and that all nonzero complex numbers have an inverse (used in this answer) are tightly related. The latter implies the former in general, as used in this answer. But the converse is also true _in this situation_ by some basic linear algebra: multiplication by a fixed nonzero complex number $z$ is a linear operator on a $2$-dimensional real vector space; if it has zero kernel ($z$ is no zero divisor) then it is surjective (by rank-nullity), in particular $1\in\Bbb C$ has a preimage, an inverse of $z$.

Answer (score 1):

In the end it always boils down to the fact that for $x,y\in\Bbb R$ the equation $x^2+y^2=0$ implies $x=y=0$. One possible approach is to use linear algebra. The complex numbers for a real vector space with basis formed by $1$ and $\def\ii{\mathbf i}\ii$. The operation of multiplying by $Z=a+b\ii$ is linear, and has matrix
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{pmatrix}
$$
with respect to the mentioned basis. It has determinant $a^2+b^2$, which if $Z\neq0$ is nonzero, so that the linear operator is injective, and the only element in its kernel is $W=0$.

If one does not like the asymmetry in $Z,W$ of this argument, one can multiply the matrices of multiplication by $Z$ and $W$, and use $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$. This gives the Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity, and the proof in the answer by André Nicolas.